# How to determine whether a CLI program awaits an action or is processing?

Tags: terminal

Consider the executable `pstopdf`, if I enter it into the terminal, the cursor hops to the next line and the terminal is "blocked".

[image: Screenshot of terminal executing a command]

How can I tell what the program is doing / is waiting / is processing / is awaiting an action?

Comment: Most CLI programs accept arguments and don’t have an interactive mode unless specified.  Any program that accepts input from STDIN as a default will behave as you described.  The best practice here would be to read the man page *before* executing the command to see what it does.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Don't get me wrong, you are definitely correct. I was just wondering if there is a way of observing the program "status", e.g. processing, or awaiting keyboard input.

Comment: You could potentially look for processes (with `lsof`) by a user that’s using a FIFO (first in/first out) device like a pipe, but that would require a new/sub shell to be opened.  However, that would be like trying to go from A to B by way of Z.  Just break (`Ctrl-C`) if you end up where you seem that the computer is just “waiting”.  You won’t really hurt anything.

Comment: In general, if you type a command and it just sits there like this, it's practically always waiting for input. In particular, since you didn't provide any arguments that told it what to do, it's unlikely to be doing any long computation -- what would it be computing?